# Assume $A \subset B$ and $A \neq \emptyset$. Prove $B \neq \emptyset$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

I have an exercise stating

> Assume $A \subset B$ and $A \neq \emptyset$. Prove $B \neq \emptyset$.

Is my proof adequate, or have I missed anything out? Any tips would be greatly appreciated as I am self taught new to proof writing.

Proof : As $A \neq \emptyset$ , $ \exists a , (a \in A)$. Also, as $A \subset B$ , $\forall a \in A, (a \in B)$. From this we get $\exists a , (a \in B)$. Therefore, $B \neq \emptyset$

Comment: yeah that's right

Comment: @Akababa Thank you

Comment: Your proof is perfectly correct !

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct and well-presented. Good job!

---

*Mostly posting this so this question can be finally considered to have an answer and thus be removed from the unanswered queue. Made it Community Wiki since I have nothing much of substance to add.*